# Which index should I use on binary datatype column mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, collation, b-tree-index

I am writing a simple tool to check duplicate files(i.e. files having same data). The mechanism is to generate hashes for each file using sha-512 algorithm and then store these hashes in MYSQL database. I store hashes in binary(64) unique not null column. Each row will have a unique binary hash and used to check file is duplicate or not.

-- My questions are --

1. Can I use indexes on binary column, my default table collation is latin1 - default collation?
2. Which Indexing mechanism should I use Btree or Hash, for getting high performance? I need to update or add 100 of rows per seconds.
3. What other things should I take care of to get best performance?

Answer (score 18):

1. > Can I use indexes on binary column, my default table collation is latin1 - default collation?

   Yes, you can; collation is only relevant for character datatypes, not binary datatypes (it defines how characters should be ordered)—also, be aware that `latin1` is a *character encoding*, not a collation.
2. > Which Indexing mechanism should I use Btree or Hash, for getting high performance? I need to update or add 100 of rows per seconds.

   Note that hash indexes are only available with the `MEMORY` and `NDB` storage engines, so you may not even have a choice.

   In any event, either would typically be able to meet your performance criteria—although for this particular application I see no benefit from using B-Tree (which is ordered), whereas Hash would give better performance.  Therefore, if you have the choice, you may as well use Hash.

   See [Comparison of B-Tree and Hash Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-btree-hash.html) for more information.
3. > What other things should I take care of to get best performance?

   Depends on your definition of "best performance" and your environment.  In general, remember Knuth's maxim "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*": that is, only optimise when you know that there will be a problem with the simplest approach.

Comment: I am using Innodb storage engine for hash store table, so HEAP indexing mechanism will not be available for it. I think, Btree indexing will not be bad.